# Windows batch script to unzip files in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, unzip

I want to unzip all files in a certain directory and preserve the folder names when unzipped.

The following batch script doesn't quite do the trick. It just throws a bunch of the files without putting them into a folder and doesn't even finish.

What's wrong here?

```
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip') DO (

    "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" 
)
```

Comment: Is it possible that some of your zip files have a space in the name?  If so your 1st line should be: for /F "usebackq" %%I IN (`dir /b /s "*.zip"`) DO (

Comment: Try this: `for /F "delims=" %%I IN ('dir /b /s/a-d *.zip') DO (` .

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /R "C:\root\folder" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
  "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI" 
)
```

or (if you want to extract the files into a folder named after the Zip-file):

```
for /R "C:\root\folder" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
  "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpnI" "%%~fI" 
)
```

Comment: what should i do if i need to extract the file to a different destination??

Answer (score 7):

Ansgar's response above was pretty much perfect for me but I also wanted to delete archives afterwards if extraction was successful. I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/9310115a#37ad) and incorporated it into the above to give:

```
for /R "Destination_Folder" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
  "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -aos -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI"
  "if errorlevel 1 goto :error"
    del "%%~fI"
  ":error"
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to extract to a different directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I IN (' dir /b /s /a-d *.zip ') DO (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI\%%~nI" "%%I" 
)
pause
```

Comment: @moinkhan I'd be happy to.  Which part is confusing to you?

Comment: @foxidirve pls explain the perimeters in the loop & the whole idea,how its works

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that some of your zip files have a space in the name?  If so your 1st line should be:

```
for /F "usebackq" %%I IN (`dir /b /s "*.zip"`) DO (
```

Note the use of ` instead of '
See FOR /?

Comment: And using "delims=" is necessary to handle long names.

Answer (score 0):

As PowerShell script (and without a 3rd party tool) you can run:

```
#get the list of zip files from the current directory
$dir = dir *.zip
#go through each zip file in the directory variable
foreach($item in $dir)
  {
    Expand-Archive -Path $item -DestinationPath ($item -replace '.zip','') -Force
  }
```

Taken from Microsoft forum posted by user 'pestell159'.