# How to use Windows Batch File to mass unzip files and saving them in specific folders?

Tags: windows, batch-file, unzip

I got the code to mass unzip from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077964/windows-batch-script-to-unzip-files-in-a-directory).  But it unzips everything in the folder where the batchfile exists. I want it to unzip it to specific folders or its individual folders.

Note: my bz2 files are in various folders outside the folder where the batchfile exists.

Here's the script that i used :

```
for /R "C:\Users\victor\Desktop\MASTERS\color feret\disc 1\data\images" %%I in ("*.bz2")
do ("%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpnI" "%%~fI")
```

Can someone enlighten me how to do it?
And also if possible, can anyone explain to me what are the arguments for? "x , -y -o %%dpnI " etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a batch file for this process at all. Start *WinRAR*, select all the archives you want to extract, click on **Extract To** in toolbar, select the base destination folder, check the option *Extract archives to subfolders* in *Miscellaneous* group and press button OK. That's it.

From a command line in a console window with current working directory being the directory containing all the *.bz2 files to extract:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRar.exe" x -ad -y *.bz2 C:\Temp\
```

There is no need for a **for** loop as *WinRAR* supports wildcards for archive file names.

And with option `-ad` the archive file **First.bz2** is extracted to folder **C:\Temp\First**, archive file **Other.bz2** is extracted to **C:\Temp\Other**, and so on. With checking option *Extract archives to subfolders* in GUI, you use option `-ad`.

Help of *WinRAR* contains the page **Switch -AD - append archive name to destination path**. Click in menu **Help** on **Help topics**. On tab **Contents** open **Command line mode** and open **Commands** and **Switches**. Also text file **Rar.txt** in program files folder of *WinRAR* contains a description for command **x** and the options `-ad` and `-y` and all other commands and options for console version **Rar.exe**.

But if you want to use nevertheless a **for** loop and want to know what `%%~dpnI` and `%%~fI` mean, open a command prompt window, enter either `help for` or `for /?` and read.